# org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, configuration

I am getting a problem while running spring hibernate project for

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:383)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:830)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have included following `jars` in my project

```
commons-dbcp2-2.0.1.jar
commons-pool2-2.2.jar
hibernate3.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager.jar
hibernate-validator.jar
javax.persistence.jar
jta.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar
spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-build-src-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-framework-bom-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

My `servlet-context.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="configLocation">
        <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />


<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.webapp" />

</beans:beans>
```

Some one on stackoverflow has asked for checking same version of jars file. Please help me to resolve this error as I have already same version of jars included in project

Comment: Can you check the class loading. There are high chances that some spring related jar is getting loaded from classpath on server and it's shadowing you application's lib jars. Which server are you using?

Answer (score 9):

The `needsRefresh()` method was added in Spring 4.0.x and so it can't be found in the 3.0.x version.

You need to run:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and look for a Spring core/beans jar having the 3.x.x version. If you have multiple versions of the same lib, the class-loader can pick the first one it found, and the behavior could become chaotic.

Also, you have both `hibernate3.jar` and `hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar`, so make sure you get rid of old versions.

Comment: Worked for me. There was a conflict between spring-beans 3.2.10 and 3.2.4.

Answer (score 2):

Unconfirmed but I've seen this error also from what appeared to be a Spring 3.2.5 to 3.2.8 issue; i.e. after uplift of all Spring dependencies to 3.2.8 (*except* Spring Security, remaining on 3.2.5) the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I was working in eclips spring mvc project.there my application was running well with pivotal tc server but I was getting this error when ever I was trying to run it using tomcat appache.I realized that this is because JRE with the project 1.6 and tomcat was 1.8.I upgrade the JRE to 1.8 and I was able to remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

install below maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```