# Error while starting tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, jpa, spring-data

I have an error while starting the tomcat.
I have tried with tomcat v7.0.65 and v8.5.9.
Maven builds the project successfully but tomcat does not start and gives an error. 
Spring version used : 4.0.0.RELEASE

Spring Data JPA :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Following is the stacktrace of the error.

```
Jan 06, 2017 3:24:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:368)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:908)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:618)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jan 06 15:24:03 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5050)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5712)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jan 06 15:24:03 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:888)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5050)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5712)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674760/org-springframework-beans-factory-annotation-injectionmetadata-needsrefresh)

Answer (score 0):

Update for above post as it was not accepting the dependency tree.

Following is the result for mvn dependency:tree :-

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] B2B
[INFO] Common
[INFO] CompanyMngt
[INFO] Root
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building B2B 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ B2B ---
[INFO] com.astrika:B2B:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Common 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ common ---
[INFO] com.astrika:common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.27:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.0.M1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:4.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:jar:3.1.0.CR10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:jar:3.1.0.CR10:compile
[INFO] +- nl.captcha:simplecaptcha:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:20030825.184428:compile
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:20030825.183949:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations:ehcache-spring-annotations:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:r09:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.ganyo:gcm-server:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.zeroturnaround:zt-zip:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- de.idyl:winzipaes:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] +- net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile
[INFO] \- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.4.5:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CompanyMngt 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ companymngt ---
[INFO] com.astrika:companymngt:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.astrika:common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.0.M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:4.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:jar:3.1.0.CR10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:jar:3.1.0.CR10:compile
[INFO] |  +- nl.captcha:simplecaptcha:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:20030825.184428:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:20030825.183949:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations:ehcache-spring-annotations:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:r09:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ganyo:gcm-server:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zeroturnaround:zt-zip:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.idyl:winzipaes:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.4.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-search:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-engine:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.1-rc3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-analyzers:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.solr:solr-analysis-extras:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           +- org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spellchecker:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  \- org.apache.solr:solr-commons-csv:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-smartcn:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-stempel:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Root 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ root ---
[INFO] com.astrika:root:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.astrika:common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.0.M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:4.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:jar:3.1.0.CR10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:jar:3.1.0.CR10:compile
[INFO] |  +- nl.captcha:simplecaptcha:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:20030825.184428:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:20030825.183949:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations:ehcache-spring-annotations:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ganyo:gcm-server:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zeroturnaround:zt-zip:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.idyl:winzipaes:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.4.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.astrika:companymngt:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-search:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-engine:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.1-rc3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-analyzers:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.apache.solr:solr-analysis-extras:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           +- org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           |  +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spellchecker:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           |  \- org.apache.solr:solr-commons-csv:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-smartcn:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-stempel:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:r1043:compile
[INFO] |  +- args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:r08:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] \- com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO]    \- rhino:js:jar:1.6R7:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] B2B ................................................ SUCCESS [  1.559 s]
[INFO] Common ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.428 s]
[INFO] CompanyMngt ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.191 s]
[INFO] Root ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.114 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.859 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-09T12:16:51+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/181M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```